# Two Queries in One with Active Record Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I got those two queries in rails console, but I want to make just one query with the same result. How I can do that?

Table name: companies

```
  id         :integer          not null, primary key
  name       :string
  phone      :string
  email      :string
```

Table name: users

```
  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
  role                   :integer
  tier                   :integer
  company_id             :integer
  name                   :string
  email                  :string
```

Table name: responsibles

```
  id         :integer          not null, primary key
  company_id :integer
  user_id    :integer
```

These queries:

```
user_ids = Responsible.where(company_id: 1).pluck(:user_id)
User.where(id: user_ids).agent_or_admin.tier1.pluck(:email)
```

*(edit: formatted code block)*

Comment: Please update with the specific code, you may also want to read up on how to better format your post so it can be read.

Comment: Is `Responsible` a join table for users and companies? We don't know anything about your code, help us out.

Comment: Could you post the agent_or_admin and tier1 method and where it's located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Responsible` is a join table for `User` and `Company`, you could do something like:

```
User.joins(:responsibilities).where(responsible: {company_id: 1}).agent_or_admin.tier1.pluck(:email)
```

But without knowing how things are structured in your code, I can't really do much else.

Comment: Yes, responsibles is a third table because of the relationship many to many between users and companies . I tried this query , but it did not work . I edited the description of the question with three tables. Thank you!

Comment: In what way did it 'not work'? You need to be more specific if you want us to help debug.